# Realisation of a of stochastic process described by a pearson type 4 pdf

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I have comme across a [paper](https://doi.org/10.1175/1520-0450(1972)011%3C0918:PDOVLS%3E2.0.CO;2) in my research, which attempts to model a stochastic process $X_t = \bar{X_t} + \Delta X_t$ with a **known** mean part $\bar{X_t}$ and a fluctuating error around the mean $\Delta X_t$.

The paper gives details of how the fluctuating error term is distributed :
$$
p\left(\Delta X_t \vert t\right) = \frac{\left|\frac{\Gamma\left(m+\frac{\nu}{2} i\right)}{\Gamma(m)}\right|^{2}}{\alpha \mathrm{B}\left(m-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)}\left[1+\left(\frac{x-\lambda}{\alpha}\right)^{2}\right]^{-m} \exp \left[-\nu \arctan \left(\frac{x-\lambda}{\alpha}\right)\right]
$$

Where $m, \nu, \alpha, \lambda$ are parameters of the Pearson Type 4 distribution **dependent on t**, and $B, \Gamma$ are repectively the Beta and Gamma Functions.

The objective of the paper was to derive this distribution and to link it's parameters to some physical quantities of interest, which is in itself usefull information.

However, I was wondering if it was possible to go beyound and to generate realisation of the compelte stochastic process $X_t$ for which the mean $\bar{X_t}$ is **known**.

The first idea that commes to mind is to add randomly generated samples drawn from $p\left(\Delta X_t \vert t\right)$ to the mean at each timestep $t$. However, I am concerned that this might give a rather discontinuous result, which would be somewhat in opposition with the underlying physics.

My question is therefore if there is a way to generate a smoooth realisation of this stochastic process.

I have started to look around for answers, looking at Weinstein, Brownian and O-U processes, but I have failed to find how to fit my problem within these frameworks.

Comment: I have no idea about pearson type 4 pdf, but your pdf is independent of time, seemingly. for time independent pdf the Fokker-Plank equation has an analytical solution and you basically want an inverse of it, i.e. which "drift" and "deviation" are going to produce this pdf.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've started to take a look at Fokker-Plank equations, and there already appears to be some work done on inverting these problems. Concerning the time dependence, I think it comes from the fact the parameters are time dependent in the article i've studied. I'll try to see if it is possible to extend the Fokker-Plank equation for this case also.